# Formula to extract hostname from variety of entered URL's

Tags: regex, excel-formula

Client's provide URL's in many different types of formats. I look for an Excel formula that can extract the hostname (including www if provided), all else needs to be trimmed off. Below are examples of URL's we have received and the **bold** text is the part I wish to extract in the next adjacent cell. A single-cell formula would be ideal (RIGHT, LEFT, REGEXMATCH etc), but I have not succeeded matching to all below variations, looking to community for help :-)

> http://**testing.com.my**/college/openday/?
>   utm_campaign=dec&utm_source=search&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=link
>
> http://**testing.com**?utm_source=test
>
> http://**testing.com**/?utm_source=test
>
> http://**www.testing.com.sg**/test?utm_source=test
>
> https://**www.testing.com**/asdsd?utm_source=test
>
> http://**www.testing.edu.my**/college/openday/?utm_campaign=dec&utm_source=search&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=link
>
> **testing.edu.my**
>
> **testing.com**
>
> **testing.com**/?asdomasd
>
> **www.testing.com**
>
> **www.testing.com.my**?test
>
> **www.testing.com.my**/?test
>
> **www.testing.edu.my**/openday/?utm_campaign=dec&utm_source=search&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=link
>
> **www.testing.edu.my**/college/openday/
>
> //**www.testing.com**/test
>
> //**testing.com**/ddsd?utm_source=test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that I couldn't find a shorter one for you but here you go:

```
=MID(A2,FIND(MID(E2,IFERROR(FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1),"/","|",LEN(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1),"/","")))),0)+1,30),A2),FIND(MID(MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","")))),10),1,IFERROR(IFERROR(FIND("/",MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","")))),10)),FIND("?",MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","")))),10))),LEN(MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","")))),10))+1)-1),A2)+LEN(MID(MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","")))),10),1,IFERROR(IFERROR(FIND("/",MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","")))),10)),FIND("?",MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","")))),10))),LEN(MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","")))),10))+1)-1))-FIND(MID(E2,IFERROR(FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1),"/","|",LEN(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1),"/","")))),0)+1,30),A2))
```

This is a little bit hard to explain so I also upload the logic how I went through.

[image]

First, I want to find the `first .`, then remove the prefix, and then find the position of that first good wording.  See the columns that I highlight in green.

Second, I want to find the `last .`.  But this is a little bit tricky.  You don't know how it is going to end with so I added 10 characters (you can change to a bigger value).  Then I find `/` or `?` (from your example, I believe `/` always go first) or include all words if those two characters do not exist.  Then I can retrieve the last good string and find the position.  This is all done in those yellow columns.

Lastly, in the blue columns.  I simply combined all the formulas into one single cell to show you the start and ending points.  BTW, you can also see the pertaining formulas in `row 18`.

Some tricks here that I have also learned from this exercise:

- `LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))` help you to find how many `/` (replace this character to find the one you want) in the string.
- `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","")))` can find the last `/` (replace this character to find the one you want) character in that string.  Please note I used `|` here just because this character is rare to see but you can use whichever that you don't think it will appear in your string.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the regex you are looking for is not very common since you accept to match URLs possibly starting directly with `//`.

So, inside your Excel formula, use the following regex `^(https?:)?(\/\/)?([^\/]*).*` and access the 3rd matching group when the regex matches.

Note that this will give you either the hostname, or the IP address (for IPv6 addresses, you will get `[theIPv6Address]` with carets around the address).